# Проблемы с maven в IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, jetty, freemarker

Решил пройти курс на stepic по разработке веб-сервера на java, но столкнулся с проблемой - в pom.xml составленном преподавателем (который должен работать) подсвечивается красным каждый плагин. Из-за этих проблем не подключается jetty и freemarker. Проект используется эту библиотеку и шаблонизатор, однако поскольку они не подключены, то и в исходном коде при обращении к ним IDEA не понимает, откуда их брать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Скрин [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>L1.1</groupId>
  <artifactId>L1.1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
          <finalName>server</finalName>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: А что преподаватель говорит?

Comment: должен быть установлен maven, а в настройках IDEA для maven указывается, где находится дистрибутив maven'a и пути к репозитарию и его настройкам (последние два вроде автоматом прописываются).. и IDEA сама выкачивает библиотеки что указаны в pom файле

Comment: видимо не настроен репозиторий, покажите ваш settings.xml.
если используете maven, который встроен в idea, то файл будет в папке .m2

Comment: на красную надпись наведи курсор и alt+enter - идея должна предложить обновить индексы мавена. Это может занять продолжительное время

Comment: Преподаватель ничего не говорил. Я ему не писал. Знаю, что ждать ответа там очень долго..

Comment: Maven установлен. Там,  на первом скрине, внизу, выполнена команда mvn -version, и ответ, вроде, говорит о том, что maven установлен правильно. Maven, встроенный в IDEA, здесь используется. Я также пробовал через скачанный отдельно  maven, указав в настройках путь до него, результат тот же.

Comment: @SergeiK https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B61d5dqhqJD8WDk4dUwwMFdMb0U

Comment: @SergeiK содержимое папки. setting.xml не нашел

Comment: @НикитаГордеев Да, я сразу это попробовал, подождал, пока обновит, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: если нет, тогда нужно добавить. можно загуглить пример, желательно с central repository. еще в настройках maven если не включено, то включите auto-import.

вот тут можно посмотреть что должно быть в файле: https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/apache-maven/src/conf/settings.xml

Answer (score 1):

Попросите вашего преподавателя показать настройки maven репозиториев.
Их можно найти в следующих местах:
1) Home-директория пользователя -> .m2/settings.xml
2) В Settings Intellij IDEA: "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Build Tools" -> "Maven" -> "Repositories"
3) В самих pom.xml фалах. Пример: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Answer (score 1):

Возможно в локальных данных Maven нет информации о хранящихся в главном репозитории артефактов и их версий. У меня была такая ситуация, решилась в IDEA Update Maven Indices (по Alt+Enter на любой красной зависимости) правда процесс не быстрый

Answer (score 0):

Там в правом нижнем углу выплывает табличка про import, в ней надо вклчючить возможность автоимпорта.